# Spinner default selection to "Select your item"

Tags: android

Sorry for repeated question.I have a searchable spinner.It will show some names.Defaultly it will select the first name into selection.I want it to be "Select your item".How to do that? I am getting these names from API.Iam new to android so forgive me if I asked any blunder.

```
 ArrayList<String> employeeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i=0;i<common.dataArrayList.size();i++){
                String[] data=new String[3];
                data[0]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[0];
                data[1]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[1];
                data[2]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[2];
                employeeList.add(data);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<employeeList.size();i++){
                employeeNames.add(employeeList.get(i)[1]+" - "+employeeList.get(i)[2]);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InsertRequisition.this, R.layout.item_spinner_black, employeeNames);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner);
            employeeSpinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.employee_name_value);
            employeeSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

//My spinner xml

```
 <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
                android:id="@+id/employee_name_value"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

//My post Data

```
postData="{\"Title\":\""+title.getText().toString()
            +(getIntent().hasExtra(Common.REQID)?"\",\"ID\":\""+getIntent().getExtras().getString(Common.REQID):"")//checking update or insert
            +"\",\"ReqDateFormatted\":\""+date.getText().toString()
            +"\",\"ReqForCompany\":\""+companyList.get(companySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition())[0]//Company code
            +"\",\"RequisitionBy\":\""+employeeList.get(employeeSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0? -1:employeeSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()-1)
            +"\",\"ReqStatus\":\"Open\"" +
            ",\"RequisitionDetailList\":" +
             detailItemsJSON
            +",\"userObj\":{\"UserName\":\""+userName+"\"}}";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add single item to first position with value "Select your item"

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InsertRequisition.this, R.layout.item_spinner_black, employeeNames);

//Add item to first position

dataAdapter.insert(getString(R.string.select_item), 0);

employeeSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

And in `onItemClickListener`, just do your work if selected position is not 0.

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, l) -> {
    if (position != 0) {
        position -= 1;
        //Do stuff like normal
    }
});
```

If you are using `getSelectedItemPositoion()` then

```
int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 ? 
        -1 : spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1;
```

Comment: bro "Add java.lang.String in ArrayAdapter cannot be applied". this error occuring

Comment: bro can you explain what will give in onSelectListner?

Comment: @AndroDevil also fixed, it is onItemClickListener

Comment: bro the problem is the "selected_item " is appearing on first in spinner. But It will pass value of just below it.

Comment: add if statement. if selected == 0 do nothing else selected -= 1 and do your work as nothing happen

Comment: bro actually iam passng the value  of spinner selected item as postDAta

Comment: +"\",\"RequisitionBy\":\""+employeeList.get(employeeSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition())[0]

Comment: What will i do here?

Comment: bro i added the postdata...I provided as you said..But app crashed..Help me.

Comment: "RequiitionBy" is the spinner value data

Comment: @AndroDevil post your exeption

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=-1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)

Comment: Okay, you have to add some code in case when user select nothing, In your case nothing would be -1 and not select -1 your array list. I think it is not related to your question, so you have to implement this logic by yourself

Comment: bro can anything be done here?      data[0]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[0];
                    data[1]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[1];
                    data[2]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[2];